Spring Cloud Gateway - Circuit Breaker Beans not registering
My Spring circuit breaker beans are not being registered. Does anyone know why? I'd expect there to be two beans registered, CircuitBreakerConfig and circuitBreaker
@Configuration
internal class CircuitBreakerConfig {

    @Bean
    fun circuitBreaker(): Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> {
        return Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> { factory ->
            factory.configureDefault { id ->
                Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                    .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults())
                    .timeLimiterConfig(
                        TimeLimiterConfig.custom()
                            .timeoutDuration(
                                // 4.5 seconds
                                Duration.ofSeconds(4, 500_000_000L)
                            )
                            .build()
                    )
                    .build()
            }
        }
    }

}

But nothing gets registered:

I believe my yaml settings should be ok
  # spring cloud settings
  cloud:
    # spring gateway settings
    gateway:
      metrics:
        enabled: true
        tags:
          path:
            enabled: true
      filter:
        circuit-breaker:
          enabled: true
    # spring circuitbreaker settings
    circuitbreaker:
      resilience4j:
        enabled: true
        reactive:
          enabled: true
        enable-group-meter-filter: true

